# JavaFX: Drop down (show) textfield on CheckBox select

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am making a form using scenebuilder, javaFx . I want to drop down (expand )a text field on clicking check box like accordion works.When I deselect checkbox It should again contract.there were other labels and textFields below these checkboxes ,so they should shift below when a checkbox elements expand.

```
                          <RadioButton fx:id="apply_ece" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="1033.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="203.0" text="Are you applying for ECE PhD?" />
                          <RadioButton fx:id="complete_pg" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="1058.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="292.0" text="Have you completed your Post Graduation?" />
                          <RadioButton fx:id="gate_exam" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="1115.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="Taken GATE Exam?" />
                          <RadioButton fx:id="acad_degree" layoutX="89.0" layoutY="1086.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="215.0" text="Other Academic Degrees?" />
                          <Label layoutX="92.0" layoutY="1154.0" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="438.0" text="Achievements, CV and Statement of Purpose">
                             <font>
                                <Font size="21.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
```

Comment: Is showing/hiding is enough, or you want some animation (expand/collapse)?

Comment: just showing and hiding .

Comment: Then try example code at [kick off demo app here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17014524)