# How to change JavaFX PasswordField's bullet

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to override the default `PasswordField`'s bullet into `@`. **How to do it?**

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17014524/4185959)

Comment: Also note that in Java 9, the skin classes will be public API, so you can much more easily override [`TextFieldSkin`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextFieldSkin.html) and provide your own implementation of `maskText()`.