# How do I show contents from the password field in javafx using checkbox

Tags: javafx

Im a student studying java and javafx, how do I show the password in the passwordfield using a checkbox? I am using gluon scenebuilder as my fxml editor

Comment: What I would do in FXML is start with a StacPane. I would then add a TextField and a PasswordField in that order. I would then listened to the CheckBox is isselected property. If it's selected, set the TextField text using the PasswordField text. Move the TextField toFront. When it is not checked, clear the TextField and move the PasswordField toFront.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The duplicate is listed above for the correct but more complicated way of doing this. In this answer, I am showing two examples. One with a `CheckBox` and the other with the all-seeing eye. The eye is to use a `StackPane` to layer the node. For the `CheckBox` solution, put a `TextField` and then a `PasswordField` in the `StackPane`. Bring the `TextField` `toFront` when the `CheckBox` is checked and set its text using the `PasswordField`. Clear the `TextField` when the `CheckBox` is not checked and move the `PasswordField` `toFront`. For the `All-seeing eye` example, use the same ideas but add an `ImageView` and always keep the `ImageView` `toFront`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestingGround extends Application
{
    Image image = new Image("https://previews.123rf.com/images/andrerosi/andrerosi1905/andrerosi190500216/123158287-eye-icon-vector-look-and-vision-icon-eye-vector-icon.jpg");

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    HBox passwordControl1 = createPasswordFieldWithCheckBox();
    HBox passwordControl2 = createPasswordFieldWithCheckBox();
    StackPane passwordControl3 = createPasswordFieldWithEye();
    StackPane passwordControl4 = createPasswordFieldWithEye();

    VBox root = new VBox(passwordControl1, passwordControl2, passwordControl3, passwordControl4);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

HBox createPasswordFieldWithCheckBox()
{
    PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
    passwordField.setPrefHeight(50);
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setPrefHeight(50);
    passwordField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty());

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(textField, passwordField);
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                textField.toFront();
            }
            else {
                passwordField.toFront();
            }
        });

        HBox root = new HBox(stackPane, checkBox);
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        return root;
    }

    StackPane createPasswordFieldWithEye()
    {
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        passwordField.setPrefHeight(50);
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        passwordField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty());
        textField.setPrefHeight(50);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setFitHeight(32);
        imageView.setFitWidth(32);
        StackPane.setMargin(imageView, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        StackPane.setAlignment(imageView, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        imageView.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
            textField.toFront();
            imageView.toFront();
        });

        imageView.setOnMouseReleased((event) -> {
            passwordField.toFront();
            imageView.toFront();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(textField, passwordField, imageView);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Small suggestion: do `passwordField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty());` and you don't need to worry about setting and clearing text.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about bindings after seeing your answer.

Comment: After looking at @c0der answer, This answer's `CheckBox` solutions has a flaw. If you select the checkbox and continue to type the password in the `Textfield`, the `PasswordField` is not updated with the new characters.

Comment: The fix is adding `passwordField.setText(textField.getText());` before `textField.clear();`

Comment: Binding will take care of it : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/ZuDMYloTLR

Comment: @c0der I updated this answer using your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a custom `Tooltip` to show the password:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class FxMain extends Application {

    private SimpleBooleanProperty showPassword ;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private Tooltip toolTip;
    private PasswordField pF;

    private Stage stage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        showPassword = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        showPassword.addListener((ChangeListener<Boolean>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue){
                showPassword();
            }else{
                hidePassword();
            }
        });

        final Label message = new Label("");
        Label label = new Label("Password");

        toolTip = new Tooltip();
        toolTip.setShowDelay(Duration.ZERO);
        toolTip.setAutoHide(false);
        toolTip.setMinWidth(50);

        pF = new PasswordField();
        pF.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {
            if ( showPassword.get() ) {
                showPassword();
            }
        });

        HBox hb = new HBox(10, label, pF);
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);


        checkBox = new CheckBox("Show password");
        showPassword.bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());

        VBox vb = new VBox(10, hb, checkBox, message);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vb,300,100));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void showPassword(){
        Point2D p = pF.localToScene(pF.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxX(), pF.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxY());
        toolTip.setText(pF.getText());
        toolTip.show(pF,
                p.getX() + stage.getScene().getX() + stage.getX(),
                p.getY() + stage.getScene().getY() + stage.getY());
    }

    private void hidePassword(){
        toolTip.setText("");
        toolTip.hide();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks, both methods work, now I can continue c: