# How to mask & unmask characters of JFXPasswordField in Password field itself in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, jfoenix

I have designed this Login page in JavaFX.

[image]

I want when I click on Eye button next to JFXPasswordField onPressed password should be shown in Text format in PasswordField itself.

And when I released mouse button i.e. Eye button release Password should be encoded in Black dots as normal.

In swing i achieved this using

to decode -

```
String password = String.valueOf(txtCurrentPassword.getPassword());
txtCurrentPassword.setText(password);
txtCurrentPassword.setEchoChar((char) 0);
```

And to encode -

```
txtCurrentPassword.setEchoChar('\u2022');
```

Please help me to achieve this Design code using JavaFX.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Interesting. This *should* be possible by subclassing `TextFieldSkin` and overriding the `maskText()` method. However, I can't see a way to trigger a repaint when the mouse is pressed on the button (or generally, when a condition changes). @Sedrick's approach in the linked question is one way, but feels a bit heavy-handed.

Comment: @James_D. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014012/how-to-unmask-a-javafx-passwordfield-or-properly-mask-a-textfield Uluk's answer extends `TextFieldSkinn`. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Thanks for your response I have used this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049990/how-do-i-show-contents-from-the-password-field-in-javafx-using-checkbox)

Comment: @Sedrick I don't think that does use a subclass of `TextFieldSkin`: it just shows the old implementation of `PasswordFieldSkin` (which doesn't exist in the current version: they merged the functionality into `TextFieldSkin`). The issue still remains; I can't find a way to persuade the skin that the text needs repainting when a condition changes.

Comment: I did use of StackPane `@FXML
    private void onBtnViewPasswdMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        txtUnmaskPasswd.setText(txtPassword.getText());
        txtPassword.clear();
        txtPassword.setPromptText("");
        txtUnmaskPasswd.setPromptText("Password");
        txtUnmaskPasswd.toFront();
    }
  `