# How to make password field's content visible?

Tags: javafx

I've got a password field in JavaFX, how can I make its content visible (not with circles) if it's possible?
I found this post about it but it's for checkboxes, I'm instead changing it manually.

[How to unmask a JavaFX PasswordField or properly mask a TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014012/how-to-unmask-a-javafx-passwordfield-or-properly-mask-a-textfield)

I also got this problem with password fields that I can't change their text using the `setText` method.

```
public class LoginSignUpPage {
    public TextField signUpUsername;
    public PasswordField signUpPassword;
    public PasswordField loginPassword;
    public TextField loginUsername;
    
    private boolean areLoginTextFieldsFilled(TextField userName, PasswordField passWord) {
        boolean isInfoCorrect = true;
        /*if (userName.getText().equals("")) {
            userName.setText("enter a username");
            userName.setStyle("-fx-text-fill : RED;-fx-border-color : RED;");
            isInfoCorrect = false;
        }*/

        if (passWord.getText().equals("")) {
            passWord.setText("enter a password");
            passWord.setStyle("-fx-text-fill : RED;-fx-border-color : RED;");
            passWord.setVisible(true);
            isInfoCorrect = false;
        }

        return isInfoCorrect;
    }

    public void login(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        areLoginTextFieldsFilled(loginUsername, loginPassword);
    }
}
```

But `setVisible` doesn't work

Comment: there is nothing special toggling the visibilty of the mask manually (or via a binding to a checkBox), just set it to always unmasked. If you have trouble doing that, it's time to work through a basic fx tutorial :) As to your second problem (you shouldn't combine several problems into a single question): something wrong in the code you are not showing - same procedure as always when having debugging problems: [mcve] required

Comment: you have to set the custom skin that's implemented in the duplicate answer (either via css, or override createDefaultSkin, or setting via the setter)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049990/how-do-i-show-contents-from-the-password-field-in-javafx-using-checkbox/60061206#60061206

Comment: @Sedrick ,I'm so grateful for your answer. This really solved my problem with no complication :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the provided example works. You can simply replace the checkbox with a `boolean` and use it with an event.

```
boolean passToggle = true;
public void togglevisiblePassword(ActionEvent event) {
    if (passToggle) {
        passText.setText(pass_hidden.getText());
        passText.setVisible(true);
        passHidden.setVisible(false);
        passToggle = false;
    } else {
        passHidden.setText(pass_text.getText());
        passText.setVisible(false);
        passHidden.setVisible(true);
        passToggle = true;
    }
}
```

For a detailed solution please provide your own code or further detail.

Comment: I've tried this before.when I setVisible(true), nothing happens. I'm gonna provide a few code, just a moment

Comment: please note that in java the naming convention is to use camelCase and not snake_case for variable names

Answer (score 0):

The password field has one property that can be set the text in bullets. This method `maskText(String txt)` stays on skin.. you can replace this with a new Skin. When you type the method `maskText` test if you can replace in bullets.. use one `boolean` to inform.. you can reuse this code from another event. it's an example.

```
control.setSkin(new PassowordFieldSkin(control));
```

```
public class PasswordFieldSkin extends GNTextFieldSkin {
    private boolean shouldMaskText = true;

    public GNPasswordFieldSkin(PasswordField textField) {
        super(textField);
        createViewAction();
    }

    private void createViewAction() { 
        getActionButton().setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            TextField textField = getSkinnable();

            shouldMaskText = !shouldMaskText;

            textField.setText(textField.getText());
            textField.end();
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected String maskText(String txt) {
        if (getSkinnable() instanceof PasswordField && shouldMaskText) {
            int n = txt.length();
            StringBuilder passwordBuilder = new StringBuilder(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                passwordBuilder.append(BULLET);
            }

            return passwordBuilder.toString();
        } else {   
            return txt;
        }
    }
}
```