# PasswordField 'bullets' are not Showing Up Properly in Android App Built Using Gluon Client Plugin

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

I am using [HelloFx](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloFX) project from `gluon client samples`. And used `Java 11.0.10` with`gluon client plugin 0.1.41` to build APK.

I've added default javafx TextField(`javafx.scene.control.TextField`) and PasswordField(`javafx.scene.control.PasswordField`).

When I run the app directly in desktop (linux), I was able to type inside the password field and the 'bullets' appear properly.
[image: hellofx-password-field-bullets issue]

But when I built APK and tested in an android device, the bullets are not rendered correctly, they are shown as boxes.
[image]

So, I've created a new skin to change the 'mask character' of password field to `\u2022` as shown in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014524/9561302). In desktop, it worked with no issues. In android device the characters are properly shown as bullets but when I tap on that field the keyboard either doesn't show up or hides if it is already showing up.

Here's the `PasswordFieldSkin.java`:

```
public class PasswordFieldSkin extends TextFieldSkin {
    public static final char BULLET = '\u2022';

    public PasswordFieldSkin(PasswordField passwordField) {
        super(passwordField);
    }

    @Override
    protected String maskText(String txt) {
        TextField field = getSkinnable();
        int n = field.getLength();
        StringBuilder passwordBuilder = new StringBuilder(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            passwordBuilder.append(BULLET);
        }

        return passwordBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Here's the `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hellofx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>HelloFX</name>

    <properties>
        <main.class>hellofx.HelloFX</main.class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.6</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
        <client.maven.plugin.version>0.1.41</client.maven.plugin.version>
        <charm.version>6.0.6</charm.version>
        <glisten.afterburner.version>2.0.5</glisten.afterburner.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.10</attach.version>
        <connect.version>2.0.1</connect.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added jackson dependency here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added JavaTime data type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                     <target>${client.target}</target>
                     <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                     <reflectionList>
                        <list>hellofx.Person</list>
                        <list>com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory</list>
                     </reflectionList>
                     <nativeImageArgs>
                        <nativeImageArg>--allow-incomplete-classpath</nativeImageArg>
                     </nativeImageArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>ios</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>android</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

And finally, here's the main method:

```
public class HelloFX extends Application {

    private Label parseStatusLabel = new Label("");
    
    private String serializedString = null;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        Label label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(HelloFX.class.getResourceAsStream("/hellofx/openduke.png")));
        imageView.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setText("Username");
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        passwordField.setSkin(new PasswordFieldSkin(passwordField));
        passwordField.setText("Password");

        VBox root = new VBox(30, imageView, label, textField, passwordField, parseStatusLabel);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(HelloFX.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: The TextField on Android uses its own [TextFieldSkinAndroid](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/android/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextFieldSkinAndroid.java), so you can't override PasswordFieldSkin, without losing that skin that manages the keyboard. The good news is that this is a known issue and was [fixed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8269026) recently, and it should be available in the next version of the plugin (1.0.3).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Good to know that it's already fixed.

Comment: In theory, you can already test plugin 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT, it requires this repo: `<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>sonatypee</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>`, and make sure you "migrate" to the latest version of the rebranded `gluonfx` plugin: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_upgrading_from_previous_versions