# How to increase the PasswordField text when seen on a mobile device?

Tags: android, javafx, gluon-mobile

This [JavaFX control](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/PasswordField.html) doesn't seem to have a GluonFX equivalent for the mobile device environment. On the desktop, the circle char that masks user input looks fine. But on the Android the same char is as small as tapping paper with the tip of an ink pen.

I've tried

```
.password-field .text {
    -fx-font-size: 15;
}
```

and

```
passwordField.setFont(new Font(15));
```

but neither seem to change it. Is this just how it is for now? No way to make those black circles look bigger on the phone to the User?

Comment: Maybe use the [MaterialFX password field instead](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/blob/main/materialfx/src/main/java/io/github/palexdev/materialfx/controls/MFXPasswordField.java).

Comment: Note there were [bugs](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8269026) in the display of the [JavaFX PasswordField bullet character rendering on android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208352/passwordfield-bullets-are-not-showing-up-properly-in-android-app-built-using-g), that are fixed in recent releases (JavaFX 17+), so ensure you are using a recent JavaFX version.

Comment: The mask text is customizable by overriding [TextFieldSkinAndroid](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/fdc88341f1df8fb9c99356ada54b25124b77ea6e/modules/javafx.controls/src/android/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextFieldSkinAndroid.java#L78) maskText, or if the standard skin is used, overriding the same method in the [TextFieldSkin](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/0a785ae036f48c736b65df865a3b93f954d46fe5/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextFieldSkin.java#L675).

Comment: Similarly, MaterialFX provides a CSS stylable [hideCharacter](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/blob/main/materialfx/src/main/java/io/github/palexdev/materialfx/controls/MFXPasswordField.java#L304). I'm am little surprised the standard PasswordField doesn't allow the character to be as easily customized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
.password-field .text {
    -fx-font-size: 15;
}
```

because the inner `Text` node has its font property [bound](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextFieldSkin.java#L202) to the TextField/PasswordField control, and when the latter is set, it overrules it.

However, as you mentioned, this doesn't work either:

```
passwordField.setFont(new Font(15));
```

If you use Gluon Mobile, the `glisten.css` stylesheet applies the Roboto font, and the password field gets `Roboto, regular, 13.3pt`.

You can verify this by adding a listener:

```
passworldField.fontProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("Font: " + nv));
```

which results in something like:

```
Font: Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=15.0]
Font: Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=13.300000190734863]
Font: Font[name=Roboto, family=Roboto, style=Regular, size=13.300000190734863]
```

So it ends up using the usual "small" font.

But this works:

```
.password-field {
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
}
```

as it is applied after the Roboto font is set (your css stylesheet is applied at the end).

```
Font: Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=15.0]
...
Font: Font[name=Roboto, family=Roboto, style=Regular, size=19.999999523162843]
```

(Note that on Android there is some font scaling applied as well).

If the bullet symbol is still too small, you can use a bigger font size.

See https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+2022): Only with 28+ you will get a more visible symbol.

The only caveat of using large font sizes is that the caret gets too tall.

Comment: Perhaps using some way to set the hideCharacter to a large circle [U+2B24](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+2B24), might be an alternative.

Comment: @jewelsea, yes if that unicode works with Roboto fonts, that could work. However, the [bullet char](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/commit/13cffbaad4068177d2d3239fa297302c3f94c217#diff-1aae808f38da2f99b6e1286c9a9189a92cd27c07274b7e8a60e7aee4fa7b9af4R43) used to mask the text is quite hidden in the Android skin class, so nothing to do unless we change its source code again...