# How to implement the password field as shown in the following image by inheriting TextField?

Tags: javafx

How to implement the password field as shown in the following image by inheriting TextField?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [How to unmask a JavaFX PasswordField or properly mask a TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014012/how-to-unmask-a-javafx-passwordfield-or-properly-mask-a-textfield)

Comment: Or just use [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/wiki/Text-Fields).